# Scanf while loop and EOF processing

Tags: c, null, while-loop, scanf, eof

I have a text file we must process, in the format

dd - day
mm - month
yyyy - year
x,y,w,z - temperatures

dd,mm,yyyy,x,y,z,w

```
1,1,2010,20.8,19.2,29.3,20.9
2,1,2010,22.5,15.5,30.7,23.3
3,1,2010,21.4,14.5,21.5,18.9
4,1,2010,27.6,13.4,23.9,18.2
5,1,2010,25,16,26.1,18.3
6,1,2010,23.6,16.1,27.6,21.8
...
29,1,2010,23.5,17.5,30.2,19.6
30,1,2010,36.2,13.4,27.3,20.5
31,1,2010,37.2,17.1,26.6,21.5
1,2,2010,24.9,16.9,27.7,22.6
2,2,2010,35.2,16.7,27.7,22.7
3,2,2010,34.8,21.6,27.3,21.4
...
1,12,2010,26.6,16.5,20.1,17.2
2,12,2010,27.2,17.2,24.3,18.5
3,12,2010,30,17.2,24.4,19.8
...
30,12,2010,23.7,14.2,26.5,20
31,12,2010,41.1,14.9,27.2,21.4
```

We have not been taught to use arrays to process this data, only functions, if/else statements, loops (while/for) and operations.

I need to process the data for each month separately. My main code is contained in a `while (scanf("%d,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f", &dd, &mm, &yyyy, &x, &y, &z, &w) ==7) {}` loop.

Below is my code:

```
while (scanf("%d,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f", &dd, &mm, &yyyy, &melmax, &melmin, &sydmax, &sydmin) ==7) {
        if (totallinesread==0) {
            currentmonth = mm;

            printf("Stage 4\n=======\n");

        }

        if (mm == currentmonth) {
            daysinmonthcounted+=1;
            /*other totals*/


        }else if (mm !=currentmonth){


            /*can execute code here as needed such as generating graphs etc*/
            printf("0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)\n");
            printf("%d\n", daysinmonthcounted);


            /* make new currentmonth = mm, reset days counted = 1 */
            currentmonth = mm;
            daysinmonthcounted = 1;
        }



        totallinesread+=1;
}
```

Output:

```
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
31
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
28
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
31
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
30
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
31
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
30
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
31
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
31
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
30
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
31
0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)
30
(Note missing december 31 days at the end)
```

I am finding that this works and outputs as I wanted to (currently only printing the total days in each month) but it is skipping out on the last month altogether. I figure it has something to do with the end of the file (EOF) and because there is no next 'mm' value for the if statement to use (`currentmonth != mm`) then it is stopping and not allowing me to process any additional calculation code for December.

Is there some way for this to work? I've read that `scanf(EOF) = -1`, which should work with `currentmonth != mm`?

The data text file can be assumed to have no errors or duplicate entries and is in ascending order.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT #3 - just show the whole code instead of just edits to make things clearer]

> int scanned;
>
> while ((scanned = scanf("%d,%d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f", &dd, &mm, &yyyy, &melmax, &melmin, &sydmax, &sydmin)) ==7) {
>
> ```
>    if (totallinesread==0) {
>        currentmonth = mm;
>
>        printf("Stage 4\n=======\n");
>
>    }
>
>    if (mm == currentmonth) {
>        daysinmonthcounted+=1;
>        /*other totals*/
>
>
>    }else if (mm !=currentmonth){
>
>
>        /*can execute code here as needed such as generating graphs etc*/
>        printf("0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)\n");
>        printf("%d\n", daysinmonthcounted);
>
>
>        /* make new currentmonth = mm, reset days counted = 1 */
>        currentmonth = mm;
>        daysinmonthcounted = 1;
>    }
>
>    totallinesread+=1;
>
> }
>
> if ((scanned == EOF) && (daysinmonthcounted > 1)){
>
>        /*can execute code here as needed such as generating graphs etc*/
>        printf("0----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5 (x 10, degrees C)\n");
>        printf("%d\n", daysinmonthcounted);
>
>        /* make new currentmonth = mm, reset days counted = 1 */
>        currentmonth = mm;
>        daysinmonthcounted = 1;
> }
> ```

Comment: @typo.pl I've made the changes, and the calculation code doesn't seem to be working, so I played around with || and switching the parenthesis around but to no avail?

Comment: Where's the calculation code? Are the variables for the calculation code declared only inside the while-loop?

Comment: The variables (others and scanned) are declared outside the while loop. The if statements are inside the while loop. I'm planning on calculating the totals as they are read (`mm=currentmonth`) and outputting/displaying any graphs etc when `mm!=currentmonth` and resetting the totals. Sorry if I was unclear, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @typo.pl, oops, the display code is currently a placeholder for the future calculations/displays to show that I have the correct data, in this case both printf lines :)

Comment: I changed the if-statement condition after the while-loop, give the updated code a try and see if that helps.

Comment: @typo.pl, gave it a go as well, no luck (not running the second part else if). I've pasted the code I have so far with your edits as I'm not sure where to post my revised code: http://pastebin.com/KpHgXGQ9 - thanks again!

Comment: From your pastebin entry, you didn't understand the description of my edits, so I just edited my answer to include my edits in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write your loop to break out of middle of it:

```
 while(1) {
   failed = 0;
   if (sscanf(....) != 7) {
     mm = 99; /* invalid month */
     failed = 1;
   };
   /* check for month end */
   if (failed) {
      break;
   };
   ...
 }
```

Comment: We don't need to detect for any invalid months, data is assumed correct. Just don't know how to go about changing my loop so that it'll read all the data and process till the very end month in the txt file, like December (or any other month that's last)